# When I'll receive social security

Tags: united-states, canada, non-resident, social-security

I am Canadian and have worked in USA from Jun 2000 - Dec 2006. I have paid all the taxes, Can I get back my social security which I paid during my stay in USA?

Answer (score 4):

Social Security tax is a tax that people working in the US must pay. You cannot "get it back".

Comment: Worse yet, since the OP has not worked for 40 quarters in the US as yet, he is not eligible (at this time) to receive any Social Security _benefits_ as a result of the Social Security tax paid thus far.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Yes, but the US might have a treaty with his country that allows it to be counted for social security in his country.

Comment: @user102008 if so, you should add that to your answer, preferably with a source

Comment: Try https://www.ssa.gov/international/Agreement_Pamphlets/canada.html